# Could not parse as expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new in Spring and Thymleaf.I'm having an issue when trying to transfer my object to template.Here's an error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: 
Could not parse as expression: "$(payments.comment)" (user/profile:13)
```

Could you help me a little bit. Thanks to all.

[That is my GetMapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Xy6.png)

[That is my Thymleaf template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iPBy.png)

Comment: Would be better/easier for other people, if you include the code as text instead of screenshots. The problem possibly is that you use `$(...)` instead of `${...}` for payments.comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using parentheses:

```
$(payments.comment)
```

Use curly braces instead:

```
${payments.comment}
```

Note that `{}` is not the same as `()`